# Turning several Enumerables into one

Tags: ruby, enumerable

Is there a way to get several Enumerable objects to appear as a single Enumerable without flattening it into an Array? Currently I've written a class like so, but I feel there must be a built-in solution.

```
class Enumerables
  include Enumerable

  def initialize
    @enums = []
  end

  def <<(enum)
    @enums << enum
  end

  def each(&block)
    if block_given?
      @enums.each { |enum|
        puts "Enumerating #{enum}"
        enum.each(&block)
      }
    else
      to_enum(:each)
    end
  end
end

enums = Enumerables.new
enums << 1.upto(3)
enums << 5.upto(8)
enums.each { |s| puts s }
```

As a simple example, it needs to be able to accept an infinite enumerator like so.

```
inf = Enumerator.new { |y| a = 1; loop { y << a; a +=1 } };
```

Comment: Last line is equivalent to `inf = 1.step`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all. Use [`Enumerable::Lazy#flat_map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator/Lazy.html#method-i-flat_map) with `.each.lazy` on elements:

```
inf = Enumerator.new { |y| a = 1; loop { y << a; a += 1 } }
[(1..3).to_a, inf].lazy.flat_map { |e| e.each.lazy }.take(10).force
#⇒ [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Thanks! Just what I'm looking for. I'll wrap that up into a little function. BTW I can't find documentation for `force`. I see it's just an alias for `to_a`.

Comment: I see your point. It is literally just an alias for `to_a`: `rb_define_alias(rb_cLazy, "force", "to_a");` I found a bit of documentation in passing in `Enumerator::Lazy#new`: "*When the enumerator is actually enumerated (e.g. by calling force), obj will be enumerated and each value passed to the given block.*" Curious oversight that it's not a documented method.

Comment: Lazy? I must study it. It seems that `1..Float::INFINITY` works as well instead of `inf`. Isn't it?

Comment: @iGian as well as `1.step`, yes.

Answer (score 4):

Well, it might be done with standard library using [`Enumerator`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerator.html). The advantage of this approach would be it returns the *real* enumerator, that might be mapped, reduced etc.

```
MULTI_ENUM = lambda do |*input|
  # dup is needed here to prevent
  #  a mutation of inputs when given
  #  as a splatted param
  # (due to `input.shift` below)
  input = input.dup.map(&:to_enum)
  Enumerator.new do |yielder|
    loop do
      # check if the `next` is presented
      #  and mutate the input swiping out
      #  the first (already iterated) elem
      input.first.peek rescue input.shift
      # stop iteration if there is no input left
      raise StopIteration if input.empty?
      # extract the next element from 
      #  the currently iterated enum and
      #  append it to our new Enumerator
      yielder << input.first.next
    end
  end
end

MULTI_ENUM.(1..3, 4.upto(5), [6, 7]).
  map { |e| e ** 2 }

#⇒ [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49]
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure I understand all that. The `Enumerator::new` docs are unclear and the Enumerator::Yielder docs are blank. Could you annotate it with some comments? Also, is the `dup` necessary?

Comment: Updated. Basically, the `Enumerator` is something that either calls `yield` or raises `StopIteration` when there are no more elements. It stays behind the internal implementation of `to_enum`.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get it. `input.dup` is just a shallow clone of the Array of arguments so you can `input.shift` rather than use a counter. `input.first.peek rescue input.shift` advances to the next enum when the current one is empty (I've not seen `resuce` as a statement modifier before). `raise StopIteration if input.empty?` ends the block when there's no enums left. `yielder << input.first.next` gets the next value off the current enum and yields it.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I am not sure, though, that this solution is somehow better than yours. Honestly, I like the class and delegation to nested `enum` more.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this solution, maybe is close to what you already tried:

```
def enumerate(*enum)
  enum.each_with_object([]) { |e, arr| arr << e.to_a }.flatten
end

enumerate( 1..3, 5.upto(8), 3.times, 'a'..'c' ).each { |e| p e }

# => 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1, 2, "a", "b", "c"
```

Or (same mechanics):

```
def enumerate(*enum)
  enum.flat_map { |e| e.to_a }
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Using `arr << e.to_a` means all the enumerated objects are turned into array, so it won't work for my purposes. For example, feed it `inf = Enumerator.new { |y| a = 1; loop { y << a; a +=1 } };` and it will consume all memory.

Comment: Within the frames of this solution one does not need to flatten, just use `Array#concat`.